# Using maven properties in citrus testcase

Tags: maven, properties, citrus-framework

I would like to use properties defined in maven pom.xml in a citrus test case.

Depending on environment a different profile is activated which then defines different hostnames, ports, ...
In the citrus testcase I would like to use those maven properties to direct the requests to the correct host depending on environment.

How can this problem be solved? 
did try the env() and systemProperty() functions, they did not provide me with the values though.
Additionally I did try to use the spring approach and tried setting
hostname=@hostname.property.from.maven@
unfortunately this did not work either.

Versions used:

- Citrus Framework 2.7.5
- Maven 3.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Citrus tests are executed in Maven with maven-failsafe plugin (or maven-surefire if you want). So you need to pass your system properties to that plugin configuration for test execution.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <foo.server.host>127.0.0.1</foo.server.host>
        <foo.server.port>8080</foo.server.port>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The system properties are now visible to the Maven test execution and therefore you can use the properties in Spring and Citrus components. You can use Spring's property placeholder configurer for instance.

The Maven failsafe plugin configuration is also able to resolve Maven project properties.

```
<properties>
  <server.host>127.0.0.1</server.host>
  <server.port>8080</server.port>
</properties>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <foo.server.host>${server.host}</foo.server.host>
        <foo.server.port>${server.port}</foo.server.port>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You should now be able to set these properties based on Maven profile activation and environment settings.